# N+1 queries in ModelSerializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Comment.includes(:replies).without_replies
```

This way I get all the comments. I write API. And I use ActiveModelSerializer`

Comment have a relationship with the user. `belongs_to :user`

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment'

  attributes :id,
             :user_image_url

  def user_image_url
    object.user.image_url
  end
end
```

I need to get a picture of the user who left a comment.
Method `user_image_url`.
It's all good.
But the `bullet` displays a message.

```
GET /api/v1/comments?page=1&per_page=20
USE eager loading detected
  Comment => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:user]
Call stack
  /app/serializers/comment_serializer.rb:27:in `user_image_url'
```

I did this. `Comment.includes(:replies, :user).without_replies` But nothing, why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Comment.includes(:replies, :user).without_replies` ?